# Ubuntu, No Wifi Adapter

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, live-usb, iwlwifi

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04.3 as a persistent storage, live USB version on an old Seagate external drive. I'm getting a "No Wifi Adapter Found" error in the Wifi settings once I boot into this Ubuntu Drive.

My network adapter readout from 'lspci' is `00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak] (rev 10)`

I dowloaded the corresponding linux supported drivers and copied it to /lib/firmware folder. After restarting my computer I still get the same error message. I double checked the /lib/firmware folder for the .ucode file and it was still there. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: We don't  know what drivers you installed or where you downloaded them from. What does "lsmod | grep iwl" tell you? And what does "dmesg | grep iwl" tell you? And why didn't you use the update-manager?

Answer (score 0):

It happens very often. I have done one of these three:
1. Try to connect through an ethernet connection and then do update& upgrade.
2. Connect an USB Wifi adapter, it would surely give signal to help update & upgrade
3. Use the generic wpa_suplicant solution. It works every time.